# Is there a simple command to create a copy/mirror

Tags: mirror

Is there a simple command to create a copy/mirror any object by choosing any face along the geometry. The modeling software 3D Wings has that command and it's extremely useful.

Comment: The selected face is supposed to be used as mirror plane?

Comment: Precisely. Any face could be used to create a mirror along that face's plane to create a copy that will be part of the same object, welded at that mid point. For example, if working on a car, modeling one half will allow that middle face to be used as a mirror plane to produce the whole.